# SignatureDoesNotMatch - Query String Parameters (AWS Signature Version 4)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, query-string

I am using AWS Signature Version 4 to pre sign URL for GET requests. I had the entire module working for the sample code AWS had on their documentation. When I tried using it on my own s3 bucket (after changing all the example values to my real values), it gave me a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error. I have been trying countless hours to see what I am missing or doing wrong in my code. I am sure it is something miniscule but I cannot catch the reason why this is calculating a different signature than AWS's.

The parameters will be appending to the end of my GET requests as the return statement submits them back (and not sent through the headers in the request).

Here is the module I created.

```
require 'openssl'

module AwsPresignUrl
  extend self
  SECRET_KEY = ENV.fetch("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
  ACCESS_KEY = ENV.fetch("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
  METHOD = "GET"
  REGION = "us-east-2"
  EXPIRES = 10000
  HOST = "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
  SERVICE = "s3"

  def get_signature_key(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName)
    kDate    = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', "AWS4" + key, dateStamp)
    kRegion  = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, regionName)
    kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, "aws4_request")
  end

  def generate_signed_url(path: "/")
    t = Time.now.utc
    amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    date_stamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    credential_scope = [date_stamp, REGION, SERVICE, 'aws4_request'].join("/")
    amz_credential = uri_encode(path: [ACCESS_KEY, credential_scope].join('/'))
    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'

    # Task 1: Create a Canonical Request For Signature Version 4
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html
    # payload_hash = OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256").hexdigest("")
    canonical_uri = uri_encode(path: path)
    signed_headers = "host;x-amz-algorithm;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-credential;x-amz-date;x-amz-expires;x-amz-signedheaders"
    payload_hash = "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"
    canonical_headers = ["host:" + HOST, 
                         "x-amz-algorithm:" + algorithm,
                         "x-amz-content-sha256:" + payload_hash, 
                         "x-amz-credential:" + amz_credential,
                         "x-amz-date:" + amz_date,
                         "x-amz-expires:" + EXPIRES.to_s,
                         "x-amz-signedheaders:" + signed_headers
                        ].join("\n") + "\n"
    canonical_query_string = "X-Amz-Algorithm=#{algorithm}" +
                             "&X-Amz-Credential=#{amz_credential}" +
                             "&X-Amz-Date=#{amz_date}" + 
                             "&X-Amz-Expires=#{EXPIRES}" +
                             "&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=#{payload_hash}" +
                             "&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=#{signed_headers}"

    canonical_request = [METHOD, canonical_uri, canonical_query_string, canonical_headers,
                         signed_headers, payload_hash].join("\n")

    canonical_request_digest_hash = OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256").hexdigest(canonical_request)

    # Task 2: Create a String to Sign for Signature Version 4
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html
    string_to_sign = [algorithm, amz_date, credential_scope, canonical_request_digest_hash].join("\n")

    # Task 3: Calculate the AWS Signature Version 4
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html
    signing_key = get_signature_key(SECRET_KEY, date_stamp, REGION, SERVICE)

    # Task 4: Add the Signing Information to the Request
    # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html
    signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', signing_key, string_to_sign)

    return  "?X-Amz-Algorithm=#{algorithm}" +
            "&X-Amz-Credential=#{amz_credential}" +
            "&X-Amz-Date=#{amz_date}" + 
            "&X-Amz-Expires=#{EXPIRES}" +
            "&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=#{payload_hash}" +
            "&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=#{signed_headers}" +
            "&X-Amz-Signature=#{signature}"
  end

  def uri_encode(path:, encode_slash: true)
    encoded_uri = ""
    path.chars.each do |ch|
      if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '_' || ch == '-' || ch == '~' || ch == '.')
        encoded_uri << ch 
      elsif (ch == '/')
        encoded_uri << (encode_slash ? "%2F" : ch)
      else 
        encoded_uri << (ch.unpack('U'*ch.length).collect{|x| x.to_s 16})
      end 
    end
    encoded_uri
  end
```

Comment: where are you getting the access key and secret? If you're getting them from session remember to add the session token

Comment: Those two are coming from my .env file that holds my credential information.

Comment: Do you have the error on running the code or with the generated URLs? If it is runningthe code you should try generating new access and secret keys for the user and use them. Regards,

Comment: The error is produced when I go to s3 link and trying to do a GET request to download it. So it appears there is a piece of the code amazon is doing differently than me.

Comment: i have had a simmilar issue before and the reason was I creating the files path wrong. Can you share a generated URL or corfirm your files and folders are correct?

Comment: For me, it was a time sync issue, and what worked was to sync it up using ntpdate command: `sudo ntpdate -u in.pool.ntp.org`

Comment: @HectorMartinez An output of the url and appended parameters are `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp.com/file.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKL97DF987EXAMPLE%2F20180501%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180501T054328Z&X-Amz-Expires=10000&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-algorithm;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-credential;x-amz-date;x-amz-expires;x-amz-signedheaders&X-Amz-Signature=d7864930f3df332142d80a5d3b96af8bd3b02c44ea91f7688866c02adfd5a7df`

Comment: The word "canonical" in `canonical_query_string` refers primarily to the fact that the parameters need to be sorted. `"&X-Amz-Expires=#{EXPIRES}" + "&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=#{payload_hash}"` voilates this requirement. `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` needs to be before `X-Amz-Credential`... but in fact I suspect this shouldn't need to be included in the query string at all, since you're sending it as a header.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I think HOST should be some like "myapp.com.s3.amazonaws.com", other things to consider in your example is the file called "file.txt", Is it in the root of the bucket "myapp.com"?

Comment: @HectorMartinez If I name the HOST with the bucket name first, I lose HTTPS Protocol. And the file is also located in the root directory of the bucket.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for catching the Amz-Content. I changed that to be in the right order and it also has the same result. Amazon for their example on the SignHeader param in the URL just has `X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host`. So I think that may be what's throwing things off. I am also not sure if AWS is adding a content-type on their end to calculate it as well.

Comment: @SamH yes, query string parameters != headers.  If you are generating a signed URL for a `GET` request, `X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host` is correct.  I overlooked that this code was specifically for `GET` URLs.  There is no `Content-Type` *request* header in a `GET` request.  You only need to be concerned with the actual request.  Nothing is implicitly added/expected.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I originally included them because of their documentation saying that it needed to be, did I misunderstand it? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html `The Canonical Query String must include all the query parameters from the preceding table except for X-Amz-Signature.

Canonical Headers must include the HTTP host header. If you plan to include any of the x-amz-* headers, these headers must also be added for signature calculation. You can optionally add all other headers that you plan to include in your request.`

Comment: *"If you plan to include any of the `x-amz-*` headers"*... you aren't going to be sending any `x-amz-*` **headers** with a `GET` request.  Sorry for repeating myself, but this is what I meant when I said the query string parameters are not headers.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks I'll try it that way. I understood it as even though they are not "technically headers", they are referring to them as "headers" because these would normally be the headers in a non-get request.

Comment: Note that if you try to use your signed URL and get `SignatureDoesNotMatch`, right-click and view source and you can see exactly what the canonical request and string-to-sign for a given signed URL should look like.

Comment: That is a very understandable assumption, but incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what was wrong with my above code snippet, but I was able to find a few ways of accomplishing what I needed done.

## 1.

Add in Amazon's Ruby SDK gem.

```
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'
```

And then create a module that uses it.

```
module AwsPresignUrl
  extend self
  AWS_CLIENT = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-2', access_key_id: ENV.fetch("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), secret_access_key: ENV.fetch("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
  S3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: AWS_CLIENT)
  BUCKET = S3.bucket(ENV.fetch("S3_BUCKET_NAME"))

  def presign_url(path: "/")
    obj = BUCKET.object(path)
    url = obj.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 60)
  end
end
```

## 2.

I was actually using CarrierWave for file uploads and had overlooked that there was a built in method to doing same functionality I wanted.

In my initializer for it, I just had to comment out a line and uncomment another.

```
# config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'
config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60
```

After doing both of these, I ended up going with the second option since the S3 gem is a dependency of the CarrierWave AWS gem.